# changing value of ko.observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a ko.observable property of an object called "totalLength". While using application I would like to physically amend new value to this property. How can I do that?

I can preview the value of the demanded property by displaying:

```
alert(feature.totalLength());
```

so I know that it is the one. But when I assign a new value to it:

```
feature.totalLength() = 10;
```

I get an error:

ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Why?

Comment: Because you try to assign value to a function call.Any idea what are the `()` for?

Comment: The other commenter has a point. Whenever you see () in a programing language it's a function call. You cannot assign a value to a function call

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`ko.observable` is a function so you need to set the value like this `feature.totalLength(10)`.

Answer (score 14):

You can change value of observable like this:

```
feature.totalLength(10)
```